# Highchart: why can I not set the duration in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Relevant code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/e0qxfLtt/5/

```
$(function drawCharts() {
var chartData = [100,120,120,140,110,110];
var index = 1;
$('#b').click(function(){
    var buttonB =  document.getElementById('b');
    buttonB.disabled = true;
    if(index < chartData.length){
        var x = index, // current time
        y = chartData[index];
        $('#container').highcharts().series[0].setData([chartData[index - 1], chartData[index]]);
        setTimeout(function(){$('#container').highcharts().series[0].setData([]);}, 1000);
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(index === 1){
                $('#container1').highcharts().series[0].addPoint([0,chartData[0]]);
            }
            $('#container1').highcharts().series[0].addPoint([x,y]);
                index++;  
            }, 1000);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){buttonB.disabled = false;}, 3000);

})
$(document).ready(function () {
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container1',
            type: 'line',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    series = this.series[0];
                },
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: '' 
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            startOnTick: true,
            tickPixelInterval: 40,
            min:0,
            max:10
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            min:0,
            max:200
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            series: {
                animation: {
                    duration: 1000
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits:{
            enabled:false
        },
        series: [{
            name: '',
            data: []
        }]
    });
    var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    series = this.series[0];
                },
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: '' 
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            startOnTick: true,
            tickPixelInterval: 80,
            categories: ['a', 'b'],
            min: 0,
            max: 1
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            min:0,
            max:200
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            series: {
                animation: {
                    duration: 2000
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits:{
            enabled:false
        },
        series: [{
            name: '',
            data: []
        }]
    });
});
```

});

I would like the chart on the left to animate over a duration of 2 seconds, and used this code for the purpose:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: {
                duration: 2000
            }
        }
    }
```

However, that chart seems to animate over an instant despite the setting.

Could it due to the setTimeout functions?
If so, is there any way around that?

Comment: It is because you are using setData instead of addPoint. I think that you should be able to use addPoint to your first container as well. You can use chart.animation.duration for changing the duration of your animation as well. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/e0qxfLtt/6/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński That is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Why is the same method not working for bar charts? (code: http://jsfiddle.net/e0qxfLtt/9/)

Comment: Lets continue on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831053/highchart-how-could-i-set-animation-duration-in-case-of-adding-data-points-to-b